# Why is the object inaccessible whenever it has protected access?

Tags: c++, class, object

Given the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    int y;
    A(){
     int x = 10;
     cout << x << endl;
    }
} a;
```

There are no problems. The object declared, `a` is accessible.
But, with the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    int y;
protected: 
    A(){
     int x = 10;
     cout << x << endl;
    }
} a;
```

Creating the object `a` isn't possible and the code will not compile. Could someone please explain to me why it cannot be accessed despite the protected access modifier? What am I missing? Thank You.

Comment: "the object is within the class" - no it isn't, it's in the namespace outside the class, and so can't access the protected constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protected access specifier restricts access to member functions of the same class, or those of derived classes. In other words, the protected access specifier allows derived classes to directly access members of the base class while not exposing those members to the public. Protected inheritance is similar to private inheritance. However, classes derived from the derived class still have access to the public and protected members directly. The public (stuff outside the class) does not.